# how does a sequence can converge to more than one limit points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Since the limit point is not necessary to belong to the range set of sequence

Comment: In what context? Are you talking about a sequence of real numbers or in a general topological space?

Comment: A sequence of real numbers

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence:

$$\frac12, \frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac15,\frac45,\ldots$$

This sequence has more than one limit point, neither of which is in the range of the sequence. Does this example help at all?

**Edit:** To write the general term of this sequence is a bit clunky, but it can be done:

$$a_n=\frac12+\frac{(-1)^n\lceil n/2\rceil}{(2(2+\lceil n/2\rceil))}$$

A similar sequence, for which the general term is easier to write, is:

$$a_n=\frac12+(-1)^n\frac{n}{2n+1}$$

which gives us:

$$\frac12,\frac16,\frac9{10},\frac1{14},\frac{17}{18},\ldots$$

or even:

$$a_n=\frac{n+1+(-1)^nn}{2n+2}$$

which gives us:

$$\frac12,\frac14,\frac56,\frac18,\frac9{10}$$

Comment: Sir can you provide the formula for nth term of your given sequence

Comment: I can, and I will, but I wouldn't encourage you to think that you need an expression for the $n$th term for a sequence to be valid.